# Which is faster in terms of development time? Zend or Spring?

Tags: java, php, spring, zend-framework

I am creating a new web-based application. I narrowed development options to Zend OR Spring. 
It should start as a small database application, but could be expanded later to be an enterprise application.

Which is better in terms of Rapid development (development time) Zend framework or Spring framework?

I noticed that many people say that, in general, it is faster to write code in PHP than in JAVA.

Answer (score 2):

Spring is several things, if you are talking about a Web Framework:

- Spring MVC / Webflow
- Spring Roo [ that can create your Spring MVC / Webflow ] in 4.5 seconds
- Grails => yep, it is also Spring

Which one is faster to develop in? If you are not talking about a typing speed, then I would recommend to always go with what you [your developers] feel most comfortable with, have the most experience in.

If you are a guru in both, you would not be asking this question. But if you just like to learn, I would recommend to have a week of Zend, and then a week of Spring. By the end of two weeks, you will kill two birds => will have an understanding, weak spots of each solution *and* will be able to make a call.

Comment: Is Roo as powerful as Spring MVC ?? Does Roo sacrifice Flexibility, features, Performance, Security or anything else for fast development.

Comment: @farm, yes Roo ( and Grails ) are built _on top of_ Spring MVC, so they both have Spring MVC goodies. The answer to the second part of the question is _no_: Roo is actually a lot _faster_ to build a prototype, since you don't have to to code many things: e.g. `controller scaffold ~.web.RsvpController`

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this question can really be answered. Whomever told you that writing code in php is faster than writing code in java was either oversimplifying or confused. Each language has its benefits and drawbacks when it comes to rapid development.

You are on the right track by using a framework though.

Answer (score 1):

If you know Java very well, Spring is the way to go.

Also as you are saying it may become a full fledged enterprise application latter, I would vote for Spring. It can scale well.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you are more familiar with.

If you are not familiar with either PHP or Java, then it sounds like using Zend may be quicker, as php is pretty easy to pick up and learn quick.

But, there are frameworks which are meant to speed up development time from Spring.  The one I am talking about is [Roo](http://www.springsource.org/roo).  From the link:

> Spring Roo is a lightweight developer tool that makes it fast and easy to deliver instant results.

Of course, you will have to learn how to use it first.

Comment: Well, I am  familiar with (JEE with MVC pattern), but I have no experience in PHP, yet PHP sounds easy as explained by the tutorials of w3shoools.